# Remove form error with correct input

Tags: javascript, forms, input, passwords

I just made a registration form which will tell you in red(CSS) letters if something is wrong. However I want this text to go away as soon as the user writes it correctly. How do I do that?

```
<script>
    function validateForm2() {
        var usrnm2 = document.getElementById("usrnm2").value;
        var passw2 = document.getElementById("passw2").value;
        var cnfpassw2 = document.getElementById("cnfpassw2").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;

        if (usrnm2 == null || usrnm2 == "") {
            document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "You must enter a username";
            return false;
    }
        else if (passw2 == null || passw2 == "") {
            document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "You must enter a password";
            return false;
    }
        else if (cnfpassw2 !== passw2) {
            document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "Password does not match";
            return false;
    }
        else if (age < 18) {
            document.getElementById("error4").innerHTML = "You are not old enough to enter this site"
            return false;
    }
        else {
            alert("Congratulations, you have registered successfully!")
    }
    }
</script>
<script>
    function register2() {
        validateForm2()
    }
</script>
<form>
    Username:
    <input id="usrnm2" type="text" name="username"><p id="error1"></p>
    Password
    <input id="passw2" type="password" name="password"><p id="error2"></p>
    Confirm Password
    <input id="cnfpassw2" type="password" name="confirmpw2"><p id="error3"></p>
    Age
    <input id="age" type="number" name="age"><p id="error4"></p><br />
    <input id="bttn2" type="button" value="Register!" onclick="register2()"><br />
</form>
```

Comment: and where is the css for the "go away"?

Comment: At first you could show what you have tried (`register2` is not shown in the post). Notice also, that comparing strings to numbers might give you unexpected results.

Comment: When do you call validateForm2?

Comment: Yes sorry, its tied to     function register2() {
                    validateForm2()
                }

Comment: Keep in mind it currently works, only problem is that the red text stays there even when, say the password matches.

Comment: @JonasMohammed, http://jsfiddle.net/520ahphv/ continue in the same maneer...

Comment: Np, BUT, keep in mind that this code could/should be optimized, and re-checked. ;)

Comment: @nevermind what do I do about the final "else" statement? The verification that everything is entered correctly? `if (passw2 !== null || passw2 !=="", usrnm2 !== null || usrnm2 !== "", cnfpassw2 == passw2, age <=18){
                    alert("Congratulations, you have registered successfully!")
                }` - This didnt work

Comment: You are possibly searching for validation on change?

Comment: Unfortunatly I have reached my limit as to how many questions I may ask here. Thanks to everyone for answering, it was very helpful.
Though I now find myself pulling my hair on another issue, which has no errors in console, and I can't figure out whats wrong. The code is posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/rs7de4h7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the validation conditions into single block `if` statements, and then include a handler for returning the fields to normal when they are entered correctly:

```
if (field is entered incorrectly) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You must enter correctly";
    return false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
}

...

alert("Congratulations, you have registered successfully!");
```

You simply need to place the alert after all of the statements - it will execute as long as none of the conditions fail and thus return.

Comment: Should these handlers be called on each change?

Comment: This is possible but not required to perform the validation - I've just realised I've left something out and will update

Comment: @Wolf did my post answer your question?

Comment: This is not my question. I just felt the on-change validation would it make easier to remove the error signs.

Comment: @Wolf ah I see, you're asking when to perform the checks, not how to remove the text. I would suggest looking at the [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event - which allows you to perform these checks every time the user enters a character